# Why is `sudo` Slow When Password is Incorrect?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, sudo

When I enter my password for superuser privileges or to log in to my Linux box, if I enter it correctly, it returns immediately, granting me access. However, if I make some typo, there is a long wait before it tells me my password is incorrect. Usually, I realize that I messed up long before the computer does.

Why is this the case? As I understand it, user passwords are encrypted and stored in `/etc/shadow`, so it seems like my input should just be encrypted and compared to what is in that file for my username---which would take roughly the same time whether I enter the correct password or not. Is there some algorithmic reason, like it has to check in a bunch of extra places before it can confirm that it is incorrect? Or maybe the system knows it's an incorrect password quickly, but has to do a lot of work to keep track of incorrect login attempts. Or maybe it's just trying to punish me for screwing up.

Comment: I do hope this question is appropriate for SO. I know it's not strictly programming related, but I was hoping to learn something about maybe encryption algorithms or security best practices.

Comment: It's probably on purpose to slow down automated guessing..

Comment: I have noticed that few months ago but was not enough curious to ask. Hope an answer could be given!

Comment: It seems that they used a reasonably short (2s or so on Ubuntu) amount of time that does not increase. If you would have to guess a million passwords, it would therefore take a million seconds on average (1m * 2s / 2) = 277 hours. Not a whole lot, but a lot better than the mere seconds it would take otherwise. Some applications or operating systems use a exponental time between tries, but that can bug the hell out of users. Choose your password well!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is done totally on purpose: the reason for that is to make it impossible to guess a password using a dictionary attack.

Fast turn-around is crucial for a dictionary attack. Slowing down on incorrect passwords is a way to slow the attack to a crawl, making it impossible to execute in a meaningful time interval.

Comment: That being said, is there a way to lower the timeout?

Comment: @Shurane I honestly hope that the answer is "no".

Comment: This may not be the case for it, but Doug Gwyn said `UNIX was not designed to stop you from doing stupid things, because that would also stop you from doing clever things.` I don't mind shooting myself in the foot.

Comment: This doesn't explain it at all. Most password systems use exponential delays to prevent dictionary attacks which are both more effective and less annoying. Why doesn't sudo do that?

Answer (score 1):

The slow response from `sudo` when you enter an erroneous password is so that if you are mounting a crude brute force 'try and guess the password' attack with `sudo`, you are slowed down every time you guess wrong, so that the attack takes longer.  Those who are using it legitimately have no cause for complaint.  If you make a typo every once in a while, you won't mind.  If you really can't type your own password, it might be time to change it to something (secure) that you can type.

Comment: *"If you make a typo every once in a while, you won't mind."* Well, that's exactly why I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this question is relevant here.. I am also not sure of the correctness of my answer but I think it's for security. Making it n times slower would mean that a bruteforce attack would take n times longer.

Comment: I don't see how making an attack n times slower would help. For two reasons: 1. If we make the failure 7 times slower, and the attack gets 7 time slower... what's the deal? The attacker will wait 7 times the time and will be happy; you'd need a quadratic dependency, maybe? 2. Linear or quadratic doesn't matter, because there's no varying n here.

Answer (score 0):

Console or SSH Login is slow too. Anything that requires a password is "slowed-down" to stop brute-force attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did some research and it turns it... there *is no reason!*

I believe how `sudo` works is:

1. It loads `libpam.so`. `libpam.so` is just an ordinary library. No special permissions.
2. It asks `libpam`, "is the password for the current user correct?".
3. If `libpam` says "yes" then it runs the command as root (`sudo` is SUID so it can do that).

The delay is inserted by `libpam`. It's actually super super complicated how the delay is calculated - it's even randomised slightly. Some of the code is 25 years old so it's a bit hard to follow. I think the delay is triggered in  `pam_authenticate()` where there's this code:

```
_pam_await_timer(pamh, retval);   /* if unsuccessful then wait now */
```

And the actual delay is somehow set by calls to [`pam_fail_delay()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_fail_delay). That page has some helpful information including rationale:

> It is often possible to attack an authentication scheme by exploiting the time it takes the scheme to deny access to an applicant user. In cases of short timeouts, it may prove possible to attempt a brute force dictionary attack -- with an automated process, the attacker tries all possible passwords to gain access to the system. In other cases, where individual failures can take measurable amounts of time (indicating the nature of the failure), an attacker can obtain useful information about the authentication process. These latter attacks make use of procedural delays that constitute a covert channel of useful information.

On my RHEL 8 system the delay is set using the [fail delay PAM plugin](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_faildelay). If you edit `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` then you see this line:

```
auth        required                                     pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
```

Comment it out and the delays disappear! According to [the docs](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/pluggable-authentication-modules-pam) this is a common config for local authentication and there's also `password-auth` for remote auth, so it should be **100% safe** to remove this delay.

Some stuck-in-the-muds are probably screaming BuT lOcAl DiCtIoNaRy AtTaCkS!!1! at me right now. Don't listen to their squeals.

Recall how I said `libpam.so` is an ordinary library. It isn't SUID, so how does it actually check your password (since `/etc/shadow` is a thing now it can't just see the hash). The answer is it calls a helper binary that *IS* SUID. That is called `unix_chckpwd`, and it's probably on your `PATH`. If you run it it checks if stdin is a TTY and does some silly security theatre:

```
❯ unix_chkpwd 
This binary is not designed for running in this way
-- the system administrator has been informed
```

There's a 10 second wait at the end for literally no reason but to annoy you. I'm not joking:

```
sleep(10);  /* this should discourage/annoy the user */
```

Anyway, a thought that might be niggling at you now is "so if PAM is responsible for the delay and it's just a normal non-SUID library, how does it securely store access attempt times, and e.g. do exponential delays?"

Well... it doesn't. Don't want to wait for `sudo`'s delay? You can just run a new instance of `sudo`. But you don't even need that because `unix_chkpwd` has this comment:

```
    /*
     * we establish that this program is running with non-tty stdin.
     * this is to discourage casual use. It does *NOT* prevent an
     * intruder from repeatedly running this program to determine the
     * password of the current user (brute force attack, but one for
     * which the attacker must already have gained access to the user's
     * account).
     */
```

The delay is 100% security theatre. It does nothing to stop local dictionary attacks.

I mean even if it did, if you have access to a local user's account it's trivial to get their password without cracking it.

So what have we learned?

1. There's no point to `sudo`'s delay.
2. The security architecture of PAM is crazy.
3. PAM itself is stateless so it actually *can't* do exponential delays. I client of PAM (e.g. `sshd`) could though.

So finally, why does this delay exist if it is totally pointless? My guess is a) it make people feel secure (look at all the replies in this question saying it improves security), and b) it does make sense for remote password-based authentication, so I guess they added the feature for that and then nobody bothered to turn it off for `sudo`?